# Seamless nested scrolling (Android)

Tags: android, listview

We've all been advised against nesting views that contain a scrolling mechanism. However, in the latest Android release (5.0), the Phone app caught my attention with what seems to be a `ListView` inside of a `ScrollView`.

What really intrigued me was that the scrolling mechanism switched from the `ScrollView` to the `ListView` seamlessly.

Notice the content above the tabs is pushed out of view before the actual `ListView` begins scrolling.

I've tried duplicating this myself, but ended up unsuccessful. Here is the basic approach I was taking...

[image]

With a single, continuous touch event (no lifting of the finger) ...

As user scrolls, the `ListView` slowly covers up the `ImageView`. Once the `ImageView` is 100% covered and the `ListView` takes up the entire screen, the `ListView` begins to scroll.

I'm currently listening to touch events on the `ListView` and if the top has been reached, call `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` on the `ListView`, i.e.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  if (listViewAtTop) {
    v.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
  } else {
    v.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
  }
  return false;
}
```

The switching scrolling context works, only if you lift your finger and continue scrolling.

Is there a different approach that will achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 10):

Android 5.0 Lollipop (API 21) added nested scrolling support.

From what I can tell, both ListView (AbsListView) and ScrollView support this now (if running on API 21), but it must be enabled on the scrolling views.

There are two ways, by calling
[setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean)) or with the layout attribute android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" (which is undocumented)

To learn about how it works, or to support this for a custom widget, the key methods are these:

- [onStartNestedScroll](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#onStartNestedScroll(android.view.View,%20android.view.View,%20int))
- [onNestedScrollAccepted](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#onNestedScrollAccepted(android.view.View,%20android.view.View,%20int))
- [onNestedPreScroll](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onNestedPreScroll(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int[]))
- [onNestedScroll](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#onNestedScroll(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))
- [onStopNestedScroll](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onStopNestedScroll(android.view.View))

Unfortunately, there is no guide or training which explains how this works other than the JavaDoc itself which is rather light and there are no examples other than ScrollView.

Answer (score 9):

Add latest support package 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1' to your project. And try this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <FrameLayout ...>
           <ListView ... />
        </FrameLayout >
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

By default nested scrolling is Enabled.

Comment: What about the problem that listview doesn't fill its height in this way?

Comment: @whizzzkey.. Try adding android:fillViewport="true"to your ScrollView.

Answer (score 2):

While trying to figure out how to solve this issue myself, I found this question first; however, the answer didn't really go into too much detail. I did find a lot of good resources, so if anyone else finds themselves looking for this, I'll link them below. A term for this effect is "Sticky Scrolling".

---

An article talking about "Synchronized Scrolling".

http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/07/18/android-tips-and-tricks-synchronized-scrolling.html

---

A good video showcasing some Android scrolling tricks, "Quick Return" and "Sticky Scrolling".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PL9s0IJ9oiI

Code:
https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/scrolltricks

---

And lastly, here is another one showcasing the same effect using a listView instead of a ScrollView.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rk-tLisxSgM

Code:
https://github.com/jatago/list_sticky_scroll_trick

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative 'trick' which is quite simple... Use only a `ListView` with an added transparent header.

Answer (score 0):

I have been wanting to achieve the same effect as well. I came up finding a relevant library called ObservableScrollView in GitHub and it requires more work on the back-end via a TouchInterceptFramework but at least it did the job even for pre-lollipop devices. It also supports not only child scrollviews and listviews but also recyclerviews. Here's the link:

https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

I hope they consider nested scrolling for both lollipop and pre-lollipop devices as a part of their design standard soon. This is a good sign.

Answer (score 0):

This is  classic example of dummy layouts. Something not entirely obvious at first look. Basically the scenario is something like this.

Grey Area->FrameLayout
Followed by a listview that fills up the entire framelayout and followed by a imageview that overlaps the top half of a listview. The listview's first item is a dummy item and has a height identical to that of the imageview.
(Note: The actual data starts from the second element)

Next Step is easy
Translate the Imageview as per the scroll of the listview.

I suppose this is the best way to do that whilst avoiding nested scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following combination of attributes on your `ListView` to achieve this:

```
<ImageView ... /> <!-- must be before ListView -->

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="..." <!-- height of imageView -->
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    ...
/>
```

You don't have to manage any scrolling in your code at all, and it requires no header/dummy views in your list adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I am using something like this and it works ok I think

```
scrollView.onScroll { x, y ->
            Timber.d("ScrollView offset: ($x, $y)")

            val height = dashboardChart.measuredHeight
            val recyclerView =  viewPager.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
            if(y >= height) {
                Timber.d("ScrollView enable nested scrolling!")
                recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
            } else {
                Timber.d("ScrollView disable nested scrolling!")
                recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
            }
        }
```

Where scrollView is parent I am listening onScroll event (it is extension underneath it is viewTreeObserver.addOnScrollListener). Then depending whether I've scrolled initial offset or not I am enabling/disabling child recyclerView (similary ListView or other scrollView) scrolling.