# Android issue with implementing flings in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm having a bit of an issue using `NestedScrollView`. My use case uses 2 `NestedScrollView`, a parent and a child. I have overridden the parent's `onNestedPreScroll` method to sometimes consume scroll pixels before the child:

```
@Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
    if (dy > 0 && getScrollY() < getScrollRange()) {
        int oldScrollY = getScrollY();
        scrollBy(0, dy);
        consumed[1] = getScrollY() - oldScrollY;
    }
}
```

I have also overridden the parent's `onNestedPreFling` to consume fling before the child:

```
@Override
public boolean onNestedPreFling(View target, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    if (velocityY > 0 && getScrollY() < getScrollRange()) {
        fling((int) velocityY);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, I noticed that when the parent consumes the entirety of a scroll in `onNestedPreScroll`, the parent's `onNestedPreFling` is not being called.

From my investigation, it appears that if the parent consumes the entire scroll, the child reacts as if an `ACTION_MOVE` event with `deltaY=0` has occurred. This causes the absolute value `deltaY` to be less than `mTouchSlop` and `mIsBeingDragged` would remain being set to `false`. Since `mTouchSlop` is `false`, no fling calculation is made when an `ACTION_UP` event occurs in the child.

Is there a different approach I could be using to get the fling velocity for the parent `NestedScrollView`?

`NestedScrollView`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm hitting a dead end with the fling behavior.

Comment: I have opened an Android issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172648

Comment: I know this is older, but did you ever figure it out?  Do you maybe need to find a threshold of dy to consider it a fling and not consume it in onNestedPreScroll?