# List view inside Grid view

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I am currently developing and `Android` app and in one of my scenario I need a `ListView` inside a `GridView` cell. When I try to do that, `ListView` inside `GridView` cell doesn't scrool. I am fetching a data from `api` and it provides category and subcategory items. I want to show subcatefory items inside a `GridView`  when I click on the category item title inside `GridView` cell. Do you have any better solution ? Maybe my solution is not the best one...

Comment: Putting a scrollable inside another one is never a good idea.

Comment: Yes I know, I read about it. Do you have any suggestion? Because the customer wants that design and I have to find a way.

Comment: You may find some hints in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162350/seamless-nested-scrolling-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`RecyclerView`](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) for that. I'm not sure about problems that might appear due to nested scrollalble views BUT this view allows to interact with internal elements separately and not like `ListView`'s item. SO in theory that's possible